# Webpack split chunks aren't being executed

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have created a webpack config that has three entry points which I am trying to split when bundled. Below is my `webpack.config.js`

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all"
        }
    },
    context: path.resolve('js'),
    entry: {
        about: './about_page.js',
        home: './home_page.js',
        contact: './contact_page.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('build/js/'),
        publicPath: '/public/assets/js/',
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: 'public'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "eslint-loader",
                options: {
                    configFile: ".eslint.json"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.es6$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.es6']
    },
    watch: true
}
```

I have included the following scripts in my HTML (where `home.js` is replaced with the other relevant file names). I am getting an error that `shared.js` doesn't exist.

```
<script src="/public/assets/js/shared.js"></script>
<script src="/public/assets/js/home.js"></script>
```

When inspecting my page in chrome, I am able to see the individual javascript files and their contents, but none of the code from them is being executed. Each file currently has a console log inside which isn't being logged. but I've tried adding debuggers and writing to the page and still nothing gets hit.

Comment: Your `Webpack Config` looks fine. Make sure you added your `bundles` in to your html.

Comment: @RoopakPutheVeettil I have included the scripts in my html, see my updated question

Comment: shouldnt it be `<script src="./build/js/shared.js"></script>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assumed that the shared chunk would be called "shared.js" which is wrong.

Amend your config to be:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all",
        name: "shared"
    }
},
```

And now your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be with the way you are requiring your built js files in your html.

```
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('build/js/'),
        publicPath: '/public/assets/js/',
        filename: "[name].js"
    }
```

the public path is not for the JS files but rather for [static content like images and logos](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath). Your JS files are generated under `build/js/` as expected. Update your html to

```
<script src="./build/js/shared.js"></script>
<script src="./build/js/home.js"></script>
```

This should work as expected.

Comment: The example you linked to literally uses built javascript chunks as an example. Regardless, changing my html to point to `./build/js/` hasn't managed to fix anything either, perhaps a conflict with the `publicPath` property?

Comment: I took your code sample and removed the linting rule for now. [Seems to work](https://github.com/40x/multiple-entry-webpack)

Comment: I was unable to get it working from looking at your repository. I've uploaded what I have here: https://github.com/swillis93/multi-entry-webpack